# Symfony2 calling console command in controller from vendor

Tags: symfony, service, console, command, vendor

I want to use a console command from this bundle within my controller: http://knpbundles.com/dizda/CloudBackupBundle

The developer proposes cronjobs, however I want to use the command to backup my database from within my controller.

How would I do that?
I am getting this error message when i simply try to register this command as a service:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "backupcommandservice".
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

commands don't quite work that way.  Per the note on http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#register-commands-in-the-service-container

registering a command as a service doesn't do much other than control location and dependency injection.

if you want to call a command:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#calling-an-existing-command

that being said you shouldn't call commands from within a controller since you're basically asking to wait for this command to finish executing before you return a response.  You'd be better off just sending a request to a queue box (for example beanstalk) and have a worker perform the job.

Comment: thanks. so far I haven't even heard of beanstalk. do you know a good tutorial explaining how it works?

Comment: so someone already implemented a bundle for it so it's easy to use, you just need to set up your own queue box.  here is a link to the bundle http://knpbundles.com/armetiz/LeezyPheanstalkBundle.  As far as tutorials, sorry i'm not aware of any at the moment.